# How to run parallel Quick sort using MPI?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, quicksort

How to run this parallel quick sort using openMP
https://github.com/clasnake/parallel_sort/blob/master/quick_sort.cpp

https://github.com/clasnake/parallel_sort/blob/master/quick_sort

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have MPI installed in the system you are trying to run your program, you can first compile the cpp code using this command -

```
mpic++ quick_sort.cpp -o quick_sort
```

After you compile, An executable file named "quick_sort" will be generated. Then you can run that executable using this following command -

```
mpirun -n [number of mpi ranks you want to use] quick_sort [input_data , for example smallset.txt in the folder you shared]
```

Comment: how to install MPI for C++. I am only seeing library in python